# how to select top 10 weeks based on sort from other column

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have an issue with how to find the top 10 weekYear values, based on the sort column not by weekYear column.

The issue is that if I have to select a max value from weekYear column it will show me week 9 as a max week, but I have measured which is sorting that weekYear column how it should be.

edit:

I am getting sort from weekYear as default power bi sort and like that I am getting unordered results - max week is 9 2021 instead of 40 2021.
I have column for sorting weekYear in order, but I cannot sort new calculation based on that sortWeekYear column.

Comment: I cannot follow your description.  Please show a sample of data and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I edited question, could you please check now, it should be understandable